# Java EE 7 : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Tags: eclipse, jsp, taglib, java-ee-7

I am trying to use the following tag lib in my JSP page :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

But Eclipse shows me this error :

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

I am already having JSTL in my classpath using this dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I use WildFly 9.

I have the same problem with these 2 other taglibs :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
```

**Remark** : The following link is giving 404 HTTP error : http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar

Thank you.

Comment: use `http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar` to download the `jstl` jar.

Comment: In JavaEE 7 the namespace was changed to `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your web application uses JSTL directly, for JSTL 1.0, the namespace is http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.
In JavaEE 5, JSTL 1.1 is included, the namespace is http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.
In JaveEE 6 and JavaEE 7, JSTL 1.2 is included, the namespace is http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.

But if your web application uses JSF+Facelets, for JSF 1.x+Facelets 1.x in JaveEE 5, the namespace is http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.
For JSF 2.0+Facelets 2.x in JavaEE 6, the namespace is http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.
For JSF 2.2+Facelets 2.2 in JavaEE 7, the namespace is http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core.

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE 7 Tutorial briefly states the new URIs for JSTL in the [What Is Facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets001.htm#GIJTU) section as :

- http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core
- http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions

However, I have yet to find an implementation of the taglibs that use the URI.  So the URIs (with their recommended namespaces) should be defined as:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

And to get rid of the error you need an implementation of the JSTL loaded as a dependency in `provided` scope e.g.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `provided` scope prevents it from being included into the WAR file since the one being used by the application server should be used.