# jsp can't include my js files

Tags: javascript, jsp

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>Ajax uploader</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>UploadFile</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fileupload.UploadFile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
       <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.contextPath}/includes/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.contextPath}/includes/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.contextPath}/includes/fileUploadScript.js"></script>
```

Browser see ${request.contextPath} as text so when viewing source: src="${request.contextPath}includes/jquery.js"

Tried src="includes/jquery.js", but it provides not found error.
Any ideas?:)

Comment: something like this <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/main.js" />"></script>.

Comment: Where are your JS files located within your webapp (folder structure)?

Comment: myapp/includes/jquery.js

Comment: so this <script src="<c:url value="/includes/jquery.js" />"></script>
should be ok. Have a look also here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: when adding <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> --> error 404 cant find page

Comment: What JAVAEE do you have ?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539301/java-ee-7-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsp

Comment: It gives now: <script src="/uploader/includes/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/uploader/includes/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="/uploader/includes/fileUploadScript.js"></script>, but when debugging (F12) <html><body><h1>System message</h1><b>Script not found /ROOT/uploader/includes/jquery.js, error: no key found for Object /ROOT/uploader/includes/jquery.js</b><pre></pre></body></html>

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use? (Or other servlet engine?)

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 - but i didn't have this problem with previous simple apps with js...